# Windows 11 Single (Main Laptop Monitor) custom scaling while other monitors scaling shouldn't change

Tags: windows, laptop, scaling, dpi

I am using a laptop in a multi-monitor setup and also on the go. While the default scaling options are somewhat fine for my laptop monitor, I find 125% scaling to be too small and 150% to be too big for my taste. I have played with custom scaling and 133% works best for my laptop monitor, but my problem is that setting custom scaling to 133% also sets in on my other monitors when connecting them.

Is there any way to single out the laptop monitor and set up custom scaling?

I found this registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\PerMonitorSettings` where theoretically I can single out the laptop monitor and set a custom scaling for it, but I am not sure exactly what to set for the `DpiValue`.

Can anyone provide more information on this subject? Is it possible to set custom scaling on a single monitor? If so, what is the `DpiValue` value that I can set for 133%?